# How to make Range work with foreach statement

Tags: foreach, range, d

I have the following range:

```
struct Range {
  uint data;

  @property{
    bool empty() { return false; }
    uint front() { return data; }
    void popFront() { data = data * 2 + 1; }
  }
}
```

Trying to use it,
`foreach(c; Rnage()){ /*...*/ }` works, but with `foreach(i, c; Range()){ /*...*/ }` I get:

```
Error: cannot infer argument types
```

I need the `i` just like in something like `foreach(i, v; [1,2,3,4]){ }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ranges do not support the syntax

```
foreach(i, c; range)
```

While it seems obvious that that should work in the simple case, what that index should even be depends on the type of range and doesn't always make sense. So, no counter for the index is provided automatically by foreach, and a range has no way of providing one.

However, thanks to [tuple unpacking with foreach](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6366), you can do it by using [`std.range.sequence`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#sequence) [`std.range.zip`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#zip) with your range:

```
foreach (i, e; zip(sequence!"n"(), range))
{
}
```

By the way, you shouldn't mark `popFront` with `@property`. It doesn't make any sense. `popFront` takes no arguments and returns no value. It does not act like a variable at all. And the point of properties is to have functions which act like variables. If/when `-property`'s implementation is fully sorted out and it becomes the normal behavior (it's rather buggy at the moment, which is part of why it's a separate switch for the moment), `popFront` would not be usable as you defined it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `opApply` to implement the range, You can overload one version for the without-index style and for the with-index style:

```
struct Range {
    int opApply(int delegate(int) action){
        uint data=0;
        while(true){
            action(data);
            data=data*2+1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int opApply(int delegate(uint,int) action){
        uint i=0;
        foreach(element;this){
            action(i++,element);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work as a range with `opApply`. A type can implement both the range primitives and `opApply`, but `opApply` has nothing to do with ranges, and it won't make a type work with range-based functions. It's just a way to define iteration with `foreach`. So,  with regards to how D uses the term range, it's a complete misnomer to say that your struct here is a range.